# HttpURLConnection to Sharepoint not working on Java 7 but working for Java 5

Tags: java, rest, sharepoint

I have a piece of code to bring data from SharePoint to Unix using HttpURLConnection. The code works fine when I compile it using Java 1.5 on the server. The data is displayed on the console. But the same doesn't work when I try with Java 1.7. The Response code returned is "401". Message is "Unauthorized access".

If it is some authentication issue then why it is not coming up in the java 1.5 compiled class. Is anybody aware of any changes in the HttpURLConnection library specific to this. I only found 1 change added in Java 1.7 for streaming length limit. Any help appreciated !!

Below is snapshot of the code:

public class RestMain {

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {


            Authenticator.setDefault (new Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                            System.out.println(getRequestingScheme());
                    return new PasswordAuthentication ("Userid", "Password".toCharArray());
                }
            });

            try{
                    System.out.println(RestGet("SharePoint URL"));
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                    System.out.println("error");
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }


    public static String RestGet(String urlStr) throws IOException {
              URL url = new URL(urlStr);
              System.out.println("URL " + url.toString());
              HttpURLConnection conn =
                  (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
              System.out.println("Response Code" + conn.getResponseCode());
              System.out.println("after connect");
              if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                      throw new IOException(conn.getResponseMessage());
              }
              conn.getResponseMessage();
              System.out.println("after Response");
              // Buffer the result into a string
              BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                  new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
              StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
              String line;
              while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
              }
              rd.close();
              conn.disconnect();
              System.out.println(sb);
              return (sb.toString().substring(1,500));
            }
```

}